# benchmarking bubble sort vs merge sort using JMH

Tags: algorithm, sorting, microbenchmark, jmh

I am benchmarking an implementation for merge sort and bubble sort for a school project using JMH.
The results aren't what I expected because it seems to me that bubble sort is performing better.
so is there something wrong in my benchmarking or my implementation of the algorithms?

benchmarking code:

```
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
    @Fork(value = 1)
    @Warmup(iterations = 2)
    @Measurement(iterations = 3)
    public void init() {
        int arr[]={3,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,0,1,22,9,12,44,55,1000,99,33,333,4,33339,32,3,444,332345,32939,39493,3,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,0,1,22,9,12,44,55,1000,99,33,333,4,33339,32,3,444,332345,32939,39493,3,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,2,3,0,1,22,9,12,44,55,1000,99,33,333,4,33339,32,3,444,332345,32939,39493};

 mergeSort(arr,0,arr.length-1);
 //bubbleSort(arr);

     

    }
```

The results:

merge sort:

```
    "
# JMH version: 1.35
# VM version: JDK 16.0.2, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 16.0.2+7-67
# VM invoker: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe
# VM options: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=8379:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (auto-detected, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=false to disable)
# Warmup: 2 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 3 iterations, 10 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
# Benchmark: benchmark.testBM.init

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:50
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 2411.561 ns/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 2403.000 ns/op
Iteration   1: 2434.613 ns/op
Iteration   2: 2505.492 ns/op
Iteration   3: 2578.021 ns/op


Result "benchmark.testBM.init":
  2506.042 ±(99.9%) 1308.179 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (2434.613, 2506.042, 2578.021), stdev = 71.706
  CI (99.9%): [1197.864, 3814.221] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:50

REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.

Benchmark    Mode  Cnt     Score      Error  Units
testBM.init  avgt    3  2506.042 ± 1308.179  ns/op

Process finished with exit code 0
```

so its average is : 2506.042

bubble sort:

```
    "

# Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:50
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 1963.402 ns/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: 1815.476 ns/op
Iteration   1: 1831.914 ns/op
Iteration   2: 1863.120 ns/op
Iteration   3: 1874.605 ns/op


Result "benchmark.testBM.init":
  1856.546 ±(99.9%) 403.037 ns/op [Average]
  (min, avg, max) = (1831.914, 1856.546, 1874.605), stdev = 22.092
  CI (99.9%): [1453.509, 2259.584] (assumes normal distribution)


# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:50

Benchmark    Mode  Cnt     Score     Error  Units
testBM.init  avgt    3  1856.546 ± 403.037  ns/op

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the average is : 1856.546

so does anyone know what is the problem may be?

implementation of bubble sort:

```
   public int[] bubbleSort(int arr[])
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i< arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j =arr.length-1 ; j>=i+1;j--)
            {
                if(arr[j]<arr[j-1])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1]=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=temp;

                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

implementation of merge sort:

```
 public void merge(int[] arr, int p, int q, int r) {

    int left = q - p + 1;
    int right = r - q;

    int[] L = new int[left];
    int[] R = new int[right];

    for (int i = 0; i < left; ++i)
        L[i] = arr[p + i];
    for (int j = 0; j < right; ++j)
        R[j] = arr[q + 1 + j];

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int z = p;
    while (i < left && j < right) {

        if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
            arr[z] = L[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[z] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        z++;
    }


    while (i < left) {
        arr[z] = L[i];
        i++;
        z++;
    }

    while (j < right) {
        arr[z] = R[j];
        j++;
        z++;

    }


}

public void mergeSort(int[] arr, int p, int r) {
    if (p < r) {

        int q = p + (r - p) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, p, q);
        mergeSort(arr, q + 1, r);
        merge(arr, p, q, r);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your MergeSort implementation does tons of memory allocations. These are not for free.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a much larger input array - thousands of elements at least - to reliably see a difference in performance.

Comment: @Lee Yup! u are correct, when I used an array of size 1600 the differences were huge. bubble sort avg was :732412.897. where merge scored: 9984.169 .thank u, ur answer was helpful.

Comment: @Lee how can I mark ur answer as accepted?

Comment: @Ahmeed00 - I only posted a comment, not an answer so you can't accept it. It's probably better if you post your own answer explaining what you did and accept that one yourself.